# How to create custom message pump?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, message-queue

I am doing a small exercise where I need to create something akin to a message pump. What I have is a queue of work to do, and I want the work to be done entirely on one thread while any thread can add work to the queue to be done.

```
Queue<WorkToDo> queue;
```

The threads use a wait handle to tell the pump that there is work to do.

```
WaitHandle signal;
```

The pump just loops as long as there is work to do and then waits for the signal to start again.

```
while(ApplicationIsRunning){
    while(queue.HasWork){
        DoWork(queue.NextWorkItem)
    }
    signal.Reset();
    signal.WaitOne();
}
```

Every other thread can add work to the queue and signal the wait handle...

```
public void AddWork(WorkToDo work){
    queue.Add(work);
    signal.Set();
}
```

The problem is, if work is being added fast enough, a condition can occur where work can be left in the queue because the between the queue check for work and the the WaitHandle reset, another thread can add work to the queue.

How would I go about mitigating that circumstance without putting a costly mutex around the the WaitHandle?

Comment: I'd search for a lock-free queue.  Here's a sample: http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeStack.html

Comment: Using a WaitHandle class for synchronization is too simplistic.  The BlockingCollection class was made to solve this problem.  Backgrounder is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BlockingCollection<T>` to make implementing the queue *much* easier, as it will handle the synchronization for you:

```
public class MessagePump
{
    private BlockingCollection<Action> actions = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public void Run() //you may want to restrict this so that only one caller from one thread is running messages
    {
        foreach (var action in actions.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            action();
    }

    public void AddWork(Action action)
    {
        actions.Add(action);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        actions.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely solves my problem and it is an elegant solution. I am accepting this as the answer, however I am still very interested on how the BlockingColletion handles the problem.

Comment: @Dabloons It's straightforward enough to write one that will work.  I could provide an example that uses fairly trivial synchronization mechanisms that wouldn't have any race conditions, but it most likely wouldn't perform as well as the library implementation.  I know enough to know that I most likely couldn't write a solution as efficient as theirs on my own.  You can go decompile the library's implementation if you want to see theirs.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to do a full mutex, but can you put a lock statement

```
public void AddWork(WorkToDo work)
{
  queue.Add(work);
  lock(lockingObject)
  {
    signal.Set();
  }
}
```

use whatever you want for the locking object, most people would say that using the signal itself is a bad idea.

Responding to @500 - Server Internal Error's comment below, you could just reset the signal prior to doing the work. The following should protect things:

```
while(ApplicationIsRunning)
{
  while(queue.HasWork)
  {
    WorkItem wi;
    lock(lockingObject)
    {
       wi = queue.NextWorkItem;
       if(!queue.HasWork)
       {
          signal.Reset();
       }
    }
    DoWork(wi)
  }

  signal.WaitOne();
}
```

This way, if you have more work, the internal queue keeps going. If not, it falls out to the `signal.WaitOne()`, and we only reset if there isn't more work already queued.

The only downside here is that it's possible that we will reset multiple times in a row if work comes in while the `DoWork` is executing.

Comment: This still leaves an opportunity between the end of the while loop and the lock for the signal to get set and then incorrectly reset.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Then, shouldn't you just reset before you start the DoWork call...

Comment: modified code to resolve issue pointed out by @500-InternalServerError

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WaitOne(TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477.aspx) method so that you have a hybrid signal/polling loop.  Basically specify a timespan of 1sec of waiting at most.  This would lead to a task getting caught in that race to be held for at most a second (or whatever poll time you specify) or until another task is added to your queue.